# Should i send image as base64 string?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, base64

I am using node.js with socket.io, And send image as base64 , then convert it to image file and save. Should i use it to send videos to server from android app?

Comment: TL;DR strictly no. base64 is 33% then raw mean this increase 33% more bandwidth, 33% more memory/space. you should use streams when dealing with big file operation like either read/write I/O or send(throught network/internet)